# Union Instruction in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert following code into union Instruction in C:

```
typedef struct  InstructionTypeI_t {
        unsigned long immediate: 16;
        unsigned char rt:5; // start a new byte
        unsigned char rs : 5;
        unsigned char opcode : 6;
} InstructionTypeI_t;



typedef struct  InstructionTypeJ_t {
        unsigned long address: 26;
        unsigned char opcodce: 6;
} InstructionTypeJ_t;

typedef struct InstructionTypeR{
    unsigned long funct: 6;
    unsigned char shamt:5; // start a new byte
    unsigned char rd : 5;
    unsigned char rt : 5;
    unsigned char rs: 5;
    unsigned char opcode: 6;
} InstructionTypeR_t;


/* TODO Task (d) add union Instruction here */
typedef union Instruction{
    InstructionTypeI_t i;
    InstructionTypeJ_t j;
    InstructionTypeR_t r;
}Instruction;

union Instruction instruction

   InstructionTypeI_t i;
    InstructionTypeJ_t j;
    InstructionTypeR_t r;
```

interestingly this works

```
instruction.i=i;
instruction.j=j;
```

but this converts values wrong meaning for example instruction.i.opcode and i.opcode have different vlaues

```
instruction.i=i;
instruction.j=j;
instruction.r=r;
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: The layout of bitfields within a struct and any padding that may exist between them is implementation defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjacent bitfields have to have the same underlying type, otherwise they're not merged into the same instance of the underlying type.

I.e. by having an `unsigned long` bitfield, followed by some `unsigned char` ones, you get a full `unsigned long` variable that only holds that single bitfield, and nothing else.

The solution is to use the same type for all those bitfields, probably `uint32_t` or at least `unsigned int`. I wouldn't use `unsigned long` due to its non-portable size.